# Very Unusual PHP Behaviour

Tags: php, loose-typing

for the code below I get a page that does print task and then exit even though the value of task is zero.

```
$task = (isset($_POST['task']))?$_POST['task'] :(isset($_GET['task']))?$_GET['task']:0; 
if($task == "delete") {
    echo $task;
    exit(); 
}
```

output:

```
0
```

however if I change the first line to:

```
$task = (isset($_POST['task'])) ? $_POST['task'] :(isset($_GET['task'])) ? $_GET['task'] : NULL;
```

it will work normally, so why is it that the value of a the string 'delete' is equal to 0?

Comment: I would do whatever I could to avoid nesting ternaries, as that promotes confusion and is hard to visually understand.

Comment: Yes such a statements should be put in braces even with one short if, for example: echo `'<div>' . $i > 0 ? $i : 1 . '</div>';` would fail without brackets. `'<div>' . ($i > 0 ? $i : 1) . '</div>';`

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use $_REQUEST'task']?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

any string that can't be converted to a number is automatically converted to 0; so "delete" is 0 when comparing to a number.

you can compare using identity operator to check types as well

```
if($task === "delete") {
    echo $task;
    exit(); 
}
```

This will ensure that type is checked and return false as a result.

Answer (score 2):

You lack brackets in your ternary operator, see the example in the [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

```
$a = true ? 0 : true ? 1 : 2; // (true ? 0 : true) ? 1 : 2 = 2
```

Your example:

```
$task =
  (
    (isset($_POST['task']))
    ? $_POST['task']
    : (isset($_GET['task']))
  )
  ? $_GET['task']
  : 0;
```

So depending on your `$_POST` and `$_GET` you might even get an "invalid index" PHP warning.